# Bootstrap 4 Carousel external controls

Tags: carousel, twitter-bootstrap-4

I see the indicators in the carousel where I can click an element to go to the next slider or the previous slider.  Is it possible to directly slide to a specified carousel item from controls external to the carousel?

I was trying to add an external panel (to the carousel component) with links to specific slides. I'm trying to do something like the jquery news slider used at [easy-quiz.net](http://easy-quiz.net/). This is a jquery extention and have the callback working to change the highlighted item but want to be able to click one of the items and get the carousel to focus on the corresponding item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to achieve that is to mark up the external controls both with the `data-target` and the `data-slide-to` attributes. `data-target` identifies the carousel by id, while `data-slide-to` identifies the slide within the carousel with an integer (starting with 0).
Please see the example below with pure Bootstrap 4 markup and without additional javascript.

```html
<div class="d-flex">
    <!-- “External” carousel controls -->
    <div id="external-controls" class="col-auto btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="External carousel buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#main-carousel" data-slide-to="0" type="button">First slide</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#main-carousel" data-slide-to="1" type="button">Second slide</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#main-carousel" data-slide-to="2" type="button">Last slide</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Carousel -->
    <div id="main-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x225/422040/fff?text=Slide+1" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x225/e57a44/fff?text=Slide+2" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x225/e3d985/fff?text=Slide+3" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Other than that, you can always use the [`.carousel(number)`](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#carouselnumber) method via javascript in order to slide to a specific slide item.
So, in case you would like to create a custom –maybe simpler– markup, you could do so by writing up something as follows.

```js
$('#external-controls').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // `this` is the clicked <a> tag
    // `$.index()` returns the position of `this` relative to its sibling elements
    var target = $(this).index();
    $('#main-carousel').carousel(target);
})
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
    <!-- “External” carousel controls -->
    <div id="external-controls" class="col-auto btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="External carousel buttons">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">First slide</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Second slide</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Last slide</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Carousel -->
    <div id="main-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x225/422040/fff?text=Slide+1" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x225/e57a44/fff?text=Slide+2" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x225/e3d985/fff?text=Slide+3" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're welcome! As having the controls as external ones compared to the carousel markup was an essential part of the question (mentioned in a comment to an answer), I would suggest to incorporate that fact into the question itself. Would you mind doing that, or may I do it for you?

Comment: Thanks for this great practical answer that follows the Bootstrap convention! As the carousel cycles through each slide, the current control gets an .active class. Seems to only happen when they are a child of .carousel. Is there a practical Bootstrap way to make that happen OUTSIDE of .carousel. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is Possible, I personally use Revolution slider to achieve this.
Check out this website where I used the carousel: http://4kaststrategies.com/

at the footer of the carousel, you will see a tiny round button where you can navigate to any of the item image you want.

look up the documentation: https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/slider-revolution-jquery-5-x-documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Did you skip the Carousel **With indicators** in the documentation? That example is showing you how you can directly slide to a particular item.

The following code is being used to achieve this:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

Notice the attribute **data-slide-to**.

Comment: I did see that.  I was trying to add an external panel (to the carousel component) with links to specific pages.  I'm trying to do something like the jquery news slider used at https://easy-quiz.net/.  this is a jquery extention and have the callback working to change the highlighted item but want to be able to click one of the items and get the carousel to focus on the corresponding item.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
<button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
<button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="2"></button>
```

The simple way to use slide carousel using external button or image or anything is :

By using,

data-bs-target="(idname)"
data-bs-slide-to="(array number)"